# mysql query from 1 table that return sum of same column which different condition

Tags: mysql

I have 1 transaction tables with columns quantity.  The table looks like this

```
item     quantity
1        10
1        15
1       -10
2        10
3         5
3       -10
```

The quantity is + means buy and - means sell.  I want to count the total sum of quantity for both buy and sell group by item_id in 1 query.

The result should be like this:

```
item      buy      sell
1         25       -10
2         10         0
3          5        10
```

I tried to do query like this:

```
SELECT item, SUM(quantity>0) as buy, SUM(quantity<0) as sell FROM table GROUP BY item
```

But it gives back count of rows instead of the sum of quantity.  Any idea how to do this in 1 query?  Many thanks!

PS: I know I have to incorporate IF NULL to get item 2 return 0 instead null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select item, sum(case  when quantity>0 then quantity else 0 end) as buy, 
sum(case  when quantity<0 then quantity else 0 end) as sell
from x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user like this,

```
SELECT item,SUM(CASE WHEN quantity > 0 THEN quantity END) AS buy 
,SUM(CASE WHEN quantity < 0 THEN quantity END) AS Sell
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY item
```